# custom validation methods not working when using 'CI' in codeigniter form validation

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation, codeigniter-form-helper

hi i am using codeigniter form validation .

in my libraray i set the form validation

```
$this->ci->form_validation->set_rules ( 'businessemail', 'Business Email', 'required|xss_clean|min_length[6]|callback_valid_email_check' );
```

and my `valid_email_check` function

```
public function valid_email_check($email_address)
{
    if(!trim($email_address))
    {
        return TRUE;
    }
    $email_explode = explode("@", $email_address);

    $valid = preg_match("/^(?![_.])(?!.*[_.]{2})[a-zA-Z0-9._]+(?<![_.])$/",trim($email_explode[0]));

    if(!$valid)
    {
        $this->ci->form_validation->set_message('valid_email_check', 'The %s field contains invalid charaters');
        return FALSE;
    }
    else
    {
        return TRUE;
    }
}
```

the thing is

```
required|xss_clean|min_length[6]
```

is validating correctly , only thing the custom validation message is not working .

what have i done here , i think using `CI` , may be the issue , 
how to solve this problem , thanks in advance

Comment: why dont you use the built in valid_email method?

Comment: @shayan , i want to add some custom validations

Answer (score 1):

You say that you are setting your validation rules in a library. According to CodeIgniter's user guide this should be done in the [controller](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#validationrules) or you can save them in a [config file](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#savingtoconfig).

What's the purpose of this? -

```
if(!trim($email_address))
{
    return TRUE;
}
```

This logic seems a bit backwards to me, for example- if you passed an empty string to the function, it would return `TRUE`. Which unless I'm missing the point, isn't what you're trying to achieve.

You could just add `trim` to your `$this->ci->form_validation->set_rules` parameters and remove it from your `valid_email_check` function.

What's wrong with just using CI's `valid_email` rule? No point reinventing the wheel, unless you have a good reason.

Is this an acceptable solution? -

```
$this->ci->form_validation->set_rules ('businessemail', 'Business Email', 'trim|required|xss_clean|min_length[6]|valid_email');
```

If you have extended the `form_validation` library and this is where you function is, then you don't need to prefix it with `callback_`.

Answer (score 0):

How do you know the custom validation is not working?

What does the below return?

```
public function valid_email_check($email_address)
{
     this->ci->form_validation->set_message('valid_email_check', 'The %s field contains invalid charaters'); 
     return FALSE;
}
```

Also - where is your valid_email_check located? i.e. what file is it in?

Comment: valid_email_check function is n the same file , public function valid_email_check()

Comment: Does the function work when you run it directly (without CI's form validation)? Set it to echo something based on false or true.

Comment: _where is your valid_email_check located? i.e. what file is it in?_ - very good question. If you're extending the `form_validation` library then you don't need to prefix your function with `callback_`.